# 404 (Not Found) on custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, url

The post appears on the main page and I can see its content, but when I click on it and view the single page of the post, it says "content not found." I'm not sure what to do. It works on the "localhost" site but not on the live one that I'm fiddling with. I'm a beginner here so extra explanation would be helpful and appreciated.

This is my `single.php`:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f0675e11be46f367023b5d8c6b4f3f4b22ca73c

This is from my `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'article') );

    return $query;
}
```

I'm not sure if this makes a difference but the only thing different between the "localhost" site and the live site is the URL of the custom post-type called "article":

www.sitename.com/article/testing/ (this one is the live one and doesn't show the content)

www.sitename.com/?article=testing (this one is the localhost and does show the content)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try visiting your Settings > Permalinks page, and hitting the update button. Sounds like your .htaccess file may've gotten a little goofy and going to that page will reset it.